# Quarkus Qute Double with 2 decimal

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-qute

All is say in the title. I want to transform double in String with 2 decimals.

I tried with the example of quarkus :

```
@TemplateExtension(namespace = "str")
class StringExtensions {

   static String format(String fmt, Object... args) {
      return String.format(fmt, args);
   }

   static String reverse(String val) {
      return new StringBuilder(val).reverse().toString();
   }
}
```

And is my template

```
{str:format('%.2f', total)}
```

But It always results in NOT_FOUND.

The only way is putting :

```
    static String formatNumber(Double num) {
        return String.format("%.2f", num);
    }
```

and change my template :

```
{total.formatNumber}
```

Is there a better way ? I used the quarkus-rest-easy-qute et quarkus-qute extension both is the same.

Answer (score 1):

there was a bug in how varargs were handled for extension methods with a namespace. I've just created A PR with a fix: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/14226.

An ugly workaround is to use an additional "dummy" param in the template, e.g. `{str:format('%.2f', total, 1)}`, and ignore this param in the specified format.